# Correct positioning of diacritic mark over capital char

Tags: fonts, positioning

I'm implemeting the specific standard caled as `hip`, in which I have `'`, '=', as a diacritics marks. So I know about `\'s\'S`, but since the are not in the `hip standard` I can't use them. So I have a two kinds of letter sequences: usual letters (like `a-z`, and capital letter (like `A-Z`). And also have a control chars like (`'`, `=`, etc), which interpreted as a diacritic sign. so when I put in `tex` doc:

```
s'
```

It is correctly converted (with my font of course) to

```
ś
```

But when type the capital version of the char:

```
S'
```

Tex overdraws the char (using the same accent char), thus the char is begin overdrawn with non-capttal accent, and positioned inside that char.

So my question is how to correctly fix the virtual font file (`.vpl`) to support 
either replace that accent diacritic mark to that one, which has a upcase position, and can be correctly drawn over the capital char, or how to move the char to a new `vertical` position?

If that is impossible just with virtual font, how can I do that with `tex`?

The .vpl file is [here](https://github.com/znamenica/hiptex/blob/master/texmf/fonts/vpl/hiptex/irmucsv.vpl).

Comment: Could you give a minimal code (I can't use `s'` by default) and maybe link to this `.vpl` you are using? Thanks.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi i've updated the post

Comment: How would you discuss the Epicurus' views?

Comment: @cfr what do you mean epicirus?

Comment: Or Socrates' sandals, Epictetus' sweaters and Pythagoras' Theorem... Or is this restricted to a particular environment? It would, obviously, be clearer with an MWE.

Comment: The `.vpl` file doesn't seem to do what you want; just define a ligature for `s'` pointing to the slot for `ś` and no ligature for `S'`. If you don't have a slot for `ś`, then there's nothing you can do, because neither macros nor ligatures look back.

Comment: @egreg I just want to avoid the ligature approach in favor of the kerning. So I with to know is any way to slove it?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways how I would do that. The second one gives you more flexibility if you want to switch the font for this symbol or alike...

I do not know about your `s'` approach.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\'s\'S
\end{document}
```

---

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand*{\saigu}{\symbol{"015B}}
\newcommand*{\Saigu}{\symbol{"015A}}

\begin{document}
\saigu\Saigu{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can I just type: `S'` to have `S` with accent?

Comment: @MalSkrilew No, sorry. Please show an MWE in which this works. I have never seen that before to be true

Comment: ok, `s'` just works, `S'` doesn't